# How to increase the size of an array and add an item to the end of said array

Tags: java, arrays

Using this array I am attempting to add the item `newItem` to the array of `Item[]`

```
private Item[] itemList = new Item[0];
```

My code to add the item to the array and increase the arrays length is below:

```
    public int addItem(Item newItem) {
        Item[] newItemList = new  Item[itemList.length+1];
        for(int i=0; i< itemList.length;i++){
        newItemList[i]=itemList[i];
    }
    itemList=newItemList;
```

When executing this code I get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I believe this may be due to my `increaseArray` method which is:

```
    private void increaseArray() {
    Item[] newList = new Item[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
        newList[i] = itemList[i];
    }    
    itemList = newList;
}
```

Comment: You never call `increaseArray` in your first snippet. And btw. it would work only the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Length of your array is 0:

```
private Item[] itemList = new Item[0];
```

Therefore you cannot access the element at index 0

Comment: How would I increase the length of my array and make it work with my above code?

Comment: You cannot increase length of an array.

Comment: Try ArrayLists for that

Comment: I have edited my question with updated code, how would I now use my new array and add `newItem` to it?